# JS: How to insert object into array alphabetically by key?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following Javascript object:

```
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    d: 4
}
obj["c"] = 3
```

When I log this, the keys are in the order `a`, `b`, `d`, `c`. Is there a way to make it so that `c` is inserted between `b` and `d`?

Comment: You can't, `obj` is an **object**, not an array.
"Sorting an object" is meaningless

Comment: Objects don't have an inherent order, so no. Maps *do* have an order, but it's based on when they are inserted, so I'd take obj.keys() (an array), sort it (.sort()) then iterate through it and insert into a map. BTW, your title says "array", but you have no arrays.

Comment: let obj    = {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4};
let newObj = {};

/* insert whatever */

/* sort after keys and save into newObj */
Object.keys(obj).sort().map(e => {newObj[e] = obj[e];});

/* check newObj */
newObj;

Answer (score 1):

One method is to create a new object with `Object.fromEntries` after sorting the entries of the original object.

```js
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    d: 4
}
obj["c"] = 3;
let newObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort());
console.log(newObj);
```

Alternatively, just sort the keys before looping over them.

```js
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    d: 4
}
obj["c"] = 3;
for (const key of Object.keys(obj).sort()) {
  console.log(key, '=', obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: Objects don't have an order, so even creating a new object doesn't guarantee the same order.

Comment: @mykaf No, they do follow insertion order for non-numeric keys. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).